# Screen capture with blender

Tags: screencast

how do I record my screen with blender to answer questions? Do I need to use an external recorder or is there one built into blender?

Comment: This should help you on your way:
http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: This has been asked on blender http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056#1056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a still image or screen grab of the interface you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> and save the image.

You will be presented with the option to save to save the whole screen or just the active window.

[image]

To record a sequence of steps into a Gif file you need external sotfware.

Please read the link on meta: [What is the process for creating gifs for questions and answers?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers)

Note that when recording video you can only post a file that is under 2MB in size.