# when I render an animation it renders a different image

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I press the render button it shows me exactly the scene that i wanted, but if i click the animation button to make a sequences of pictures, it renders the wrong picture. Why is that happening ?

Comment: please make the title for the question so that it describes the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images of your render settings and show how the images are different. To make screen captures in blender read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71010/screen-capture-with-blender

Answer (score 0):

Select the camera you want to render in the outliner, then press CTRL+0 (zero numpad). That will make it the active camera.
If you did added MARKERS on the timeline (which seems to be the case) hover the timeline, locate the markers, delete them. Probably you have a binded camera as well. So delete markers, unbind camera, make selected camera active camera. Render and voilá.
Also make sure to check you´re using the SCENE's camera in the correct SEQUENCE if you´re on VSE, check also on GUI: [image]